# How given inequality proves existence of directional derivative for given function.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I am looking to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4190627/prove-or-disprove-this-function-has-directional-derivative-in-every-direction-a) question.

We have $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial n}(0,0)=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(\cos(t)h,\sin(t)h)-0}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\arctan(\cos(t)\sin(t)h^2)}{h}$$

Now I understand second answer when we get directional derivative equal to $\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}}$ but I can't understand first answer.

What we are supposed to conclude  after $$|\frac{\arctan(\cos(t)\sin(t)h^2)}{h}| \le |h|$$.

First time we get limit $0$ second time computing different way we get $\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}.$ Isn't this contradiction $?$

Answer (score 1):

$$ \lim _{h\to 0} \frac{\arctan \left (\cos (t)\sin (t)h^2 \right )}{h^2} = \lim _{h\to 0} \cos (t)\sin (t) = \cos (t)\sin (t) $$
as well as
$$ \lim _{h\to 0} \frac{f(hx,hy)}{h} = \lim _{h\to 0} \frac{\arctan (h^2xy)}{h\sqrt{h^2(x^2+y^2)}} = \lim _{h\to 0} \frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} $$
for any $(x,y)\neq 0$. No contradiction, just an oversight. The OP missed an $h$, when computing with parametrised direction.